# Java split string with RegexOption.MULTILINE

Tags: java

I want to split for example the following Sql statements by semi-colon end of line:

```
CREATE TABLE projects(
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT     NOT NULL,
   name           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE INDEX ix_tasks_project_id ON tasks (project_id);

SELECT * FROM projects WHERE name = "someName;WithSemiColon";
```

Something like:
`string.split(";$");` (but with `RegexOption.MULTILINE` applied)

Can someone please explain how do I apply the `RegexOption`?

Comment: if its posted like this you can simply split at `;` with no need of regex or anything else

Comment: Thanks. This is just an example. I want to cater for when ; appears within sql statements as well. I'm looking to split sql statements using a reliable regex.

Comment: @jack jay: where did you read this? http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: i thought it was MySql but thanks @abstractx1

Comment: @jack Ah ok, no worries. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if your file contains two statements on the same line? A comment after the semicolon? That regex is *not* reliable.

Comment: You're right. I'm enforcing that there cannot be two statements on the same line.

Comment: SQLIte also allows to have multi-line string literals. So you can do something like `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name = 'Name with semicolon;`, and on the next line, `ends here';`. It's legal, and it will fail with your regex.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Thank you so much for your help. I will use my own terminator to ensure the likelihood of this ocurring is near impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply prefix your **regular expression** with `(?m)` to enable the flag [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) so in your case it would be `(?m);$`

```
for (String s : string.split("(?m);$")) {
    System.out.printf("----> %s%n", s.trim());
}
```

**Output:**

```
----> CREATE TABLE projects(
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT     NOT NULL,
   name           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
----> CREATE INDEX ix_tasks_project_id ON tasks (project_id)
----> SELECT * FROM projects WHERE name = "someName;WithSemiColon"
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not seem to split the string.

Comment: I apologize. You're right. After looking further into the parser, the newlines were being removed. Thank you so much for your help.